# How to set the of items in legend and plot with dataframe bar plot

Tags: python, dataframe, bar-chart, legend

I would like to change the order of bars and legend in the following figure.[Bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSyzf.png)

I would like to have the order of High, Medium, low in the legend from up to down and in the plot from left to right. This is the code that I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


index2 = ["1","2 ","3 ","4 ","5 ","6 "," 7 "]
df = pd.DataFrame({'High': High_distance,'Medium': Medium_distance,
                   'Low': Low_distance}, index=index2)


ax = df.plot.bar(rot=0)
plt.ylabel('distance',fontsize=30)
plt.xticks(fontsize=30)
plt.yticks(fontsize=30)
plt.legend(fontsize=25)



plt.show()
```

The high_distance, medium_distance, and low_distance consist of 7 element.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify order of the columns as following:

```
ax = df[['High', 'Medium', 'Low']].plot.bar(rot=0)
```